# How to verify a website certificate in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, https, certificate, verify

I currently open an https connection to a web server using NSURLConnection. Everything works as it should and I am able to retrieve the page content I am after. The certificate is issued by VeriSign and I assume NSURLConnection does some work to verify the authenticity of the certificate to some extent? If I connected to the same website through mobile safari it would extract from the certificate, and display the Organization (of the website) in the navigation bar. Is it possibly to extract these same details in Cocoa Touch as I too would like to present them to the user? Also would verifying the server’s host name against that certificate be reasonable enough to assume website is legitimate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` will give you an error (`NSURLErrorDomain`) if you attempt to connect to a server with an invalid certificate (e.g. it's self signed, out of date, has the wrong host etc.). So you don't actually need to do any verification yourself, because it's all handled for you.

If you really want/need to display an SSL certificate summary in your UI, you'll need to drop down a layer from `NSURLConnection` and use low-level `CFNetwork` API instead. Once you have a `CFReadStreamRef` that's in the `kCFStreamEventEndEncountered` state, you should be able to do the following (assuming your stream handle is called `readStream`):

```
NSArray* certificates = [(NSArray*)CFReadStreamCopyProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates) autorelease]; 
if ([certificates count] > 0) { 
  SecCertificateRef certificate = (SecCertificateRef)[certificates objectAtIndex:0]; 
  NSString* description = [(NSString*)SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificate) autorelease]; 
  NSData* data = [(NSData*)SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) autorelease]; 
}
```

You'll need to decode the information held in `data` if you want to access the various properties of the certificate, but the summary held in `description` might be enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nathan, dropping a layer like you suggested did the trick! Although not really a problem, shouldn't your NSDictionary* cast be an NSArray* instead?