# How to display Server Certificate (of https requests) information inside Cocoa WebView?

Tags: cocoa, https, webview, cfnetwork

In my **mac app**, I have a **web view** & I want to show a small button (like in safari), when user visits any sites with "**https**". On clicking this button, I want to display the **certificate information.**

Here is what I have tried till now...

1) Implemented - **(void)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource**

However this delegate was not called when I visit any site with "https"

2) Since the above failed, I wrote another code (in a sample app)

```
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.onlinesbi.com"]];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and implemented

```
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

{

```
if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
    // create trust from protection space
    SecTrustRef trustRef;
    int trustCertificateCount = (int)SecTrustGetCertificateCount(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust);

    NSMutableArray* trustCertificates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:trustCertificateCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < trustCertificateCount; i++) {
        SecCertificateRef trustCertificate =  SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, i);
        [trustCertificates addObject:(__bridge id) trustCertificate];
    }
}
```

}

Now when I run the app, it comes to this delegate, however the count for certificates is 0

3) This particular link mentions use CFNetwork API [How to display certificate of HTTPS request in embedded WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590283/how-to-display-certificate-of-https-request-in-embedded-webview)

Now I am confused whether I really need to go to CFNetwork level & implement the code OR am I doing something wrong in above 1) & 2), because of which I am not getting the info…

Answer (score 3):

The code you have in *(2)* works fine for me.

```
 NSLog(@"%@", trustCertificates)
```

Prints the following:

```
(
    "<SecCertificate 0x100107c80 [0x7fff7bb4af00]>",
    "<SecCertificate 0x100107ec0 [0x7fff7bb4af00]>",
    "<SecCertificate 0x100526fe0 [0x7fff7bb4af00]>"
)
```

Moreover, importing `<SecurityInterface/SFCertificatePanel.h>` and adding the following line after your `for` loop gets a pop-up displaying the certificate chain:

```
[[SFCertificatePanel sharedCertificatePanel] runModalForCertificates:trustCertificates showGroup:YES];
```